# No display (transparent window) with OpenGL 2 and Primusrun on single buffer

Tags: c, linux, opengl, freeglut, optimus

I’m trying to make a minimalist OpenGL program to run on both my Intel chipset (Mesa) and NVIDIA card through Bumblebee (Optimus).

#### My source code (using FreeGLUT):

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
 
void display(void);
void resized(int w, int h);
 
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_SINGLE);
        glutInitContextVersion(2, 1);
        glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
        glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
        glutCreateWindow("Hello, triangle!");
       
        glutReshapeFunc(resized);
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
       
        glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0);
       
        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
}
 
void display(void)
{
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
       
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                glVertex3f(0, 0.75, 0.0);
                glVertex3f(-0.75, -0.75, 0.0);
                glVertex3f(0.75, -0.75, 0.0);
        glEnd();
       
        glFlush();
}
 
void resized(int w, int h)
{
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
        glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

When I launch directly the program (`./a.out`) on the Intel chipset, everything works. I don’t have that chance with `primusrun ./a.out` which displays a transparent window:

[image]

It is not really *transparent*, the image behind stays even if I move the window.

What's interesting is that when I change for a double color buffer (using `GLUT_DOUBLE` instead of `GLUT_SINGLE`, and `glutSwapBuffers()` instead of `glFush()`) this works both on Intel and `primusrun`.

Here's my `glxinfo`: http://pastebin.com/9DADif6X
and my `primusrun glxinfo`: http://pastebin.com/YCHJuWAA

Am I doing it wrong or is it a Bumblebee-related bug?

Comment: -1, pastebins die, SO is forever.  Edit those pastebins into the question.

Comment: What is wrong with my question? I described the problem (no display on single buffer with primusrun) and the code to reproduce it. Why is this off-topic?

Comment: Beats me, to be honest. It is perfectly valid, and I think that the discussion that datenwolf and I had pretty much nails down the cause of the issue you are having. In a nutshell, in a hybrid Integrated / Discrete GPU implementation and/or a compositing window manager, you have to swap front/back buffers in order for anything to be displayed. Frankly, these days it makes almost no sense to use single-buffered rendering anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window is probably not really transparent, it probably just shows whatever was beneath it when it showed up; try moving it around and watch if it "drags" along the picture.

When using a compositor, single buffered windows are a bit tricky, because there's no cue for the compositor to know, when the program is done rendering. Using a double buffered window performing a buffer swap does give the compositor that additional information.

In addition to that, to finish a single buffered drawing you call `glFinish` not `glFlush`; `glFinish` also acts as a cue that drawing has been, well, finished.

Note that there's little use for single buffered drawing these days. The only argument against double buffering was lack of available graphics memory. In times where GPUs have several hundreds of megabytes of RAM available this is no longer a grave argument.

Comment: Yes, it is not really transparent, it drags the picture behind as you say. Unfortunately, the `glFinish` command does not solve the issue. I totally agree on your last point, this is just an example program and I’m curious to know why it doesn’t work.

Comment: I initially had this same thought, that it was a compositing window manager issue. But then I read that the application works "properly" when you run it directly - I believe it is a similar issue, but the window manger probably is not to blame. It may be that the frame buffer has to be copied through the Intel chip for final display, and without swapping buffers the discrete GPU's contents are never copied.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: This is actually a very good theory. However it boils to the same thing: It seems like the buffer swap is required to trigger a framebuffer transfer. Given the fact that in a hybrid graphics configuration you're effectively dealing with a double buffer this makes sense. Heck if I were to develop a driver for such a situation, I'd probably not even offer single buffered visuals/pixelformats to work with in the first place.